# Create easy a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a newbie and never created a database. I want create a MySQL Database which should run on a Server (other people want use it too)

What are the essential requirements to create this in an easy way?
Are there any recommended free programs which help me to reach my goal ?

Thank you

Comment: There are thousands of online sites which can help you with this

Comment: Alongside what @SEBBINFIELD has said, you've not given us a lot of information. What environment are you running on? Is `mysqld` service installed? ...

Comment: There are no services installed... So no enviroment so far

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Get an environment

- A great VPS provider is [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=b1c2c28c6822)
- Or go for shared hosting

**2)** Install MySQL service

- Depending on your environment and OS

  - Shared hosting will probably have MySQL already installed and a nice GUI for you to use to set up your databases
- If you choose [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=b1c2c28c6822), look at their documentation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6

**3)** Set up a MySQL database and users

- Plenty of materials on this
- This should be it's own question once you've reached this stage, should you need help

I hope that will help you get further to your goal.

*Referral links are included*